# Symfony bhLDAPAuthPlugin doubt

Tags: forms, symfony1, authentication, ldap, symfony-1.4

i'm working on  a Symfony project and using the bhLDAPAuthPlugin to connect my app with the Company's Active Directory.

Its a nice plugin, easy to install and use, but i need to customize it. I have to add one parameter to the login form (i've already done this) and assign its value to the user if login succeeds (that is my trouble) but have no idea where are the user object's values assigned.

Structure of the folders and filenames are a little confusing and i don't know where to search. Please if some of you have worked with this plugin sure you can help me! i hope to have explained me well.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no knowledge about this specific plugin, but I just looked in the source.

But the authentication is handled in `/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin/modules/bhLDAPAuth/actions/actions.class.php`. In the `executeSignin()` to be specific, a form is created (by default a `bhLDAPAuthFormSignin`), and presented to the user. On POST this form is validated, and when valid, it calls the `signIn($user, $remember)` function on the user class.

The user class is defined `apps/<yourapp>/lib/myUser.php`, and probably inherits from `bhLDAPAuthSecurityUser`, defined in `/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin/trunk/lib/user/bhLDAPAuthSecurityUser.class.php`.

You can override the `signIn()` method from `bhLDAPAuthSecurityUser` in `myUser`, setting your own properties, after calling the parent `signIn()`.

Comment: I was searching for the answer and i found and understood the class structure and the path of the data trough the functions. What i did is adding to myUser my parameter as a protected attribute, and do what you said. Thank you! :D